# Why does the final output contains n-1 names while the source array is length of n?

Tags: java

Why does the final output is `n-1` length? I.e. when 2 names were entered the final loop prints only 1 name.

```
public class HelloStrangers {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        if(number==0) {
            System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
            return;
        }
        String[] strangers = new String[number];
        
        for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            strangers[i]=name;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<number;i++) {
            System.out.println(strangers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

input-output

```
2
Aasd asd
Qwer wser wre

Aasd asd
```